# dynamic datatable sorting in ascending or descending

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created dynamic table

```
 DataTable date = new DataTable();
 date.Columns.Add("date1");
```

and made fill the column name "date1" with date as

```
date1(Column name)
05-07-2013
10-07-2013
09-07-2013 
02-07-2013
```

and made fill my dynamic table

Now i want this dynamic table data to be sort as ascending or descending order

```
For eg:

date1(Column name)
02-07-2013
05-07-2013
09-07-2013 
10-07-2013
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This cannot be done with the original data table. However you can create a new, sorted one:

```
DataView view = date.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "date1 ASC";
DataTable sortedDate = view.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`DataTable.Select(filterExpression, sortExpression)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx) method.

> Gets an array of all DataRow objects that match the filter criteria,
>   in the specified sort order.

```
date.Select("", "YourColumn ASC");
```

or

```
date.Select("", "YourColumn DESC");
```

As an alternative, you can use [`DataView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) like;

```
DataView view = date.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "YourColumn ASC";
DataTable dt = view.ToTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would give in my two cents here. Instead of using a sorting algorithm which takes time and computational performance, why not instead reverse the way in which you are adding data to your data object.

This won't work for everyone's scenario - but for my own it worked out perfectly.

I had a database which listed items in an ascending order, but or ease of use I needed to reverse the way in which people could see the data (DESC) so that the newest input shows at the top, rather then the bottom of the list.

So, I just changed my for loop so instead of working from 0 -> upwards, it started from the length of the datatable (-1 to stop an overflow) and then stops when it is >= to 0;

```
private Dictionary<string, string> GetComboData(string table, int column, bool id, int idField = 0)
{
    SqlClass sql = new SqlClass(database);
    Dictionary<string, string> comboBoxData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (sql.connectedToServer)
    {
        sql.SelectResults(SQLCommands.Commands.SelectAll(table));

        for (int i = sql.table.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            string tool = sql.table.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()[column];
            string ID = sql.table.Rows[i].ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()[idField];

            comboBoxData.Add(ID, tool);
        }

    }

    return comboBoxData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using OrderByDescending()

```
          @foreach (var rca in Model.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id))
            {
                <tr class="heading">

                    <td>@rca.PBINo</td>

                    <td>@rca.Title</td>

                    <td>@rca.Introduction</td>

                    <td>@rca.CustomerImpact</td>

                    <td>@rca.RootCauseAnalysis</td>
               </tr>
             }
```